# MySQLConversionException Problem in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I am currently developing a C# MySQL Export Utility. Due to this I am not going to know the fields or the data types of each field in the table.

When I export the data from the table in the database it displays a MySQLConversionException stating that it is unable to Covert MySQL Date/Time to System.DateTime. It was doing this when I ran the code:

```
if (!reader.isDBNull(fieldCount)){}
```

However, when the exception was thrown on this line I fixed it by adding Allow Zero DateTime=true to the MySQL Connection string but not it is displaying the error when I run the code

```
string value = reader.getString(field);
```

How can I get around this issue bearing in mind I am not going to know what data type is or what the value is going to be.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: maybe try to use  var myValue = reader.getString(field);

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately didn't work. I have found out it is going wrong if it is using the default date i.e. 0000-00-00.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the raw value as object:

```
object value = reader[field];
```

Then decide what to do based on its type:

```
if (value is string)
{
    string sVal = value.ToString();
    //handle as string...
}
else if (value is DateTime)
{
    DateTime dtVal = (DateTime)value;
    //handle as DateTime...
}
else
{
    //some other type
}
```

Maybe not elegant, but should work.

Answer (score 2):

If you read DATETIME values with MySQL Connector/Net and set 'Allow Zero Datetime', then you should use the reader.GetValue() method; in this case the reader will return a MySqlDateTime object with '0000-00-00 00:00:00' value.

[Connector/Net Connection String Options Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-net-connection-options.html)

Note, than .NET DateTime.MinValue = 00:00:00.0000000, January 1, 0001.

Also, try [dotConnect for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/) components.

Answer (score 1):

I tackled a problem similar to this in an old open source project of mine.  See it [here](http://sweetsql.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/54707#917480) in my Util.DefaultConvert() method.

The trick is to use `Type.GetTypeCode()` and switch on the result.

Then implement a strict conversion for each type.  There is most likely other code in there you can check out to do what you need.  I have a MySql provider in there as well.